# I'm having difficulties with my C code output

Tags: c

I present to all of you my modest beginner code for a simple election. This codes is very not effective but, the problem is at the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    //variabel
    int k; //-> nilai berdasarkan input admin <line 10>

    printf("                                    PEMILU DIGITAL");
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("presented by Magniv_Enterprise\n\n");
    printf("Admin Input jumlah kadidat : ");
    scanf(" %i", &k);
    
    printf("\nMasukkan nama Paslon : ");
    char nama[k][200];
    for (int j; j < k; j++) {
        printf("\npaslon %i : ", j + 1);
        scanf(" %s", &nama[j]);
    }
    printf("\nJika pemungutan suara sudah selesai, inputkan nilai '-1' untuk mendapatkan hasil pemilu\n");

    //perimeters and variabel 2
    int kadidat[k];
    int loop = 1;
    int x = 0; // utk user ke berapa pada input
    int i = 0; // utk hitung jumlah pemberi suara dtung dengan 00 ato tidak
    int D; // utk menyimpan data nomer paslon yang diinputkan user
    int max;
    char maks[50];
    int draw;
    
    // start looping pemilihan suara
    while (loop == 1) {

        printf(" User- %i Memilih paslon :", x + 1);
        scanf(" %i", &D);

        x += 1;

        if (D == -1) {
            break;
        } else
        if (D > k || D <= 0) {
            printf(" Maaf, nomor yang Anda masukan salah! Silahkan mengulang lagi\n");
            x -= 1;
        } else {
            kadidat[D - 1] += 1;
            i += 1;
        }
    }//end loop
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    //Bagian Perhitungan pemenang 
    printf("\nHASIL PEMILU : \n");
    int percent;

    //for (int h = 0; h < k; h++) {
    //    printf("paslon %s punya : %i suara\n",nama[h] ,kadidat[h]);
    //}
        
    for (int L = 0; L < k; L++) {
        percent = kadidat[L] * 100 / i;
      
        if (percent > max) {
            max = percent;
            strcpy(nama[L], maks);
        }
    
        printf("Paslon %s : %d persen \n", nama[L], percent);
    }
    printf("\nPEMENANG PEMILU Dengan Suara terbanyak adalah : \n");
    printf("%s dengan %d persen suara", maks, max);

}//end main
```

Output:

```
Admin Input jumlah kadidat : ... -> based on user input

Masukkan nama Paslon : 
paslon ... : .... -> based on use input

user choose : .... -> input user

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HASIL PEMILU : -> result from my past code test
Paslon ≡kWΩ@☻ : 15 persen
Paslon ≡kWΩ@☻ : 32 persen 
Paslon ashley : -46215268 persen
Paslon ≡kWΩ@☻ : 1460 persen

PEMENANG PEMILU Dengan Suara terbanyak adalah : 
≡kWΩ@☻ dengan 1460 persen suara
```

I expect that these random `≡kWΩ@☻` thing in the output could match the same data stored in the char `nama` arrays.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't use whitespace in the 1st (string) argument of *scanf*. Please remove it everywhere.

Comment: Always check the return value of *scanf* (in your case, `if (scanf(...) != 1) { /*error*/ }`), and abort on error.

Comment: Your code has lots of buffer overflow vulnerabilities, e.g. what if the name is longer than 200 bytes (incuding the terminating `'\0'`). You may want to ask  separate question about fixing those.

Comment: See [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

- **[major]** `for (int j; j < k; j++)` has undefined behavior: `j` is uninitialized, so it may have an initial value greater than `0` or negative, causing buffer overflows or leaving entries in the arrays uninitialized as observed. **This might explain the random characters**, but another bug is even more problematic.
- **[major]** `strcpy(nama[L], maks);` should be `strcpy(maks, nama[L]);` and you should define `maks` with a length of 200 like the `nama[L]` arrays.  **This definitely explains the random output** because the `maks` array is uninitialized and you copy its contents to the candidate names that at some point have the best percentage.
- `void main()`: the prototype should be `int main(void)`
- instead of hiding the `scanf()` calls after the `printf()` prompts, you should test the return value to detect and report invalid or missing input.
- `scanf(" %s", &nama[j]);` remove the extraneous `&`, the redundant initial space, pass the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array before the null terminator and check the return value:

  ```
     if (scanf("%199s", nama[j]) != 1) {
         fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
         exit(1);
     }
  ```

Comment: Of all these issues, the uninitialized `j` is likely the culprit.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: actually, a bug can hide another bug... `strcpy` is a better culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&` in `scanf(" %s", &nama[j]);`.

*scanf* `%s` expects a `char *`, which `nama[j]` can be autoconverted to.

Comment: Did you try it? If I'm not mistaken, `&nama[j]`and `nama[j]` resolve to the same numerical address (the same way that for an array `char arr[10];` , `arr` (a.k.a. `&arr[0]`) and `&arr` are the same address. The difference is in the type (which printf and scanf, in turn, could not care less about).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica — no, you shouldn't pass the wrong pointer type to `scanf()` et al.  It just generates warnings if you have your compiler set fussy (and you ***should*** have your compiler set fussy).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Of course. And still, it will not cause any problems --  how could it? At least on an architecture where all pointers are created equal.